# Can't get any location - android

Tags: android, gps, location

i got a problem:
I can't get any location, other than Location.getLastKnownLocation(), which is not satisfying, because i need current location. Precision doesn't have to be well, 300 meters would be ok. My code looks like this:

This is the part I run when a button is pressed:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

This is my onLocationChanged() method:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lati = location.getLatitude();
        longi = location.getLongitude();
        locRes.setText("Lati: " + lati + " Longi: " + longi);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

I defined:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

In the manifest file. I've been looking everywhere on the internet and can't find solution to my problem. Location just doesn't get fixed. Before, when i was trying to use gps location i also couldn't get any. Gps wasn't even working, because there was no icon of gps working on the top bar of my phone. Have anyone got similar problem to mine? Any suggestions?

Comment: your code seems fine. Have u enabled Android to retrieve location in android settings?

Comment: yes, but now i changed it to strictly gps location and it works, but still - when i try with network provider i get nothing

Comment: Thats because location from network provider is not guaranteed. Some network does not provide location. Also due to the inaccuracy, you may need to move the device a larger distance for a location changed is detected.

Comment: thanks man, now i get why it didn't work